# Why does an entity's @OneToMany property return an empty list?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with a @OneToMany property as follows:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "code")
public class Department {

  @Id
  private String code;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private List<Employee> employees;

}
```

I have the following Spring Data repository:

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends Repository<Department, String> {
}
```

When I call `departmentRepository.findById("HR")`, I get a department object with empty list of employees. But I know HR has employees. Why are they not being returned from the query?

Update

Here's my Employee mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

  @JsonIgnore
  @EmbeddedId
  private EmployeeKey employeeKey;

  @MapsId("departmentCode")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "dept_cd")
  private Department department;

  @MapsId("serialId")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "serial_id")
  private Serial serial;

}

@Embeddable
public class EmployeeKey {

  private String departmentCode;
  private Long serialId;
}
```

**Update 2**

Looks like my only hope is to query for employees. Then, get the dept from employee

```
List<Employee> hrEmployees = employeeRepository.findByDepartmentCode("HR")
Employee anHrEmployee = hrEmployees.get(0); // hack
return anHrEmployee.getDepartment();
```

**Update 3**

I turned on SQL logging and I can see two queries being issued in response to `departmentRepository.findById("HR")`:

```
select department0_.CODE as code1_0_0_ 
from DEPARTMENT department0_ 
where department0_.CODE=?

select employees0_.DEPT_CD as code1_2_0_, employees0_.SERIAL_ID as serial_id2_2_0_, employees0_.CODE as code1_2_1_, employees0_.SERIAL_ID as serial_id2_2_1_ 
from EMPLOYES employees0_ 
where employees0_.DEPT_CD=?
```

Comment: Please show the `Employee` entity mapping.

Comment: @SternK - updated OP with `Employee` entity mapping

Comment: Try to add `@MapsId("serialId")` to the `Employee.serial` field

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. I already have that in my code. Updated OP.

Comment: Step 1. Turn on SQL logging and look at the generated queries.

Comment: @AlanHay - Thanks. I updated OP with the SQL